# Prometheus Grafana - How to visualize particular percentile calculated over selected time period

Tags: time-series, histogram, prometheus, grafana, percentile

Suppose that I have preconfigured request times buckets histograms, like the following:

```
{le="0.009786708"}  0
{le="12.884901886"} 103
{le="0.003844776"}  0
{le="0.008388607"}  0
{le="0.357913941"}  97
{le="0.447392426"}  97
{le="0.805306366"}  99
...
```

I'd like to visualize in Grafana, e.g. 95 percentile using given buckets by querying Prometheus. I know that I can use the following Prometheus query:

```
histogram_quantile(0.95,sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket[$__interval])) by (le))
```

But unfortunately it returns time series data, so I have to choose some calculation in Grafana (mean, max, min etc.) which gives me wrong value. I'd like to display just one value the same which is returned when I query Prometheus immediately using the above-mentioned query.

I hope that anyone has encountered the similar issue.

Comment: In grafana we can plot the resulting timeseries of the query. It is not necessary to select min/mean etc to plot it.